# How to wire electric blinds (UK)

Tags: wiring

I'm looking to purchase 4 remote controlled blackout roller blinds in the UK.

I'd like to have them connected to 4 switches in a single grid plate, so they match my light switches.

[image]

I'd like each switch to control a blinds individually (using a 3 position retractive switch - up/down/off).

I know that the motor used is basically a 2-core - 2 wires that would connect back to the appropriate control module to supply the voltage to drive the motor in one direction or the other:

- A +24Vdc supply will result in the motor driving in direction 1 (i.e. blind open)
- A -24Vdc supply will result in the motor driving in direction 2 (i.e. blind close)
- Removing the voltage will stop the motor (i.e. stop the blind at a mid point between open and close)

Can you suggest the best way to wire this - I assume wired to a master controller that takes a mains feed and powers all the blinds or something similar? Any ideas what I could use?

Anyone who has seen a wiring diagram would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

*Figure 1. (a) 3-wire circuit. (b) 2-wire circuit.*

- You need a 3-way (as in "positions"*), 2-pole, centre-off, switch for each blind. (* Note that "3-way switch" in North America means a two-way changeover switch as used in stairs lighting.)
- Figure 1a shows how to wire it with three wires assuming the end-of-travel switches are installed in the motor mechanism. As drawn, the motor will run until the open position is reached. The OPEN limit-switch will open and stop the motor. By switching SW1 the motor will run until the CLOSED switch opens upon which the motor will stop.
- Figure 1b shows how to reduce wiring to 2-wire by the addition of a pair of diodes. As shown, current will flow through D1 until OPEN opens, as before. When SW3 is reversed current can flow through the CLOSED switch and D2.

We have no idea if the switches or diodes are in your blinds mechanism at this time.